# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function openssl_verify()

Tags: php, wordpress, wamp

I've had to upgrade PHP from 7.0.10 to 7.3.12 on WampServer.

Since then I've been unable to update local WordPress sites, receiving error:

`Download failed.: No working transports found`

I've checked the PHP error log and I see:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function openssl_verify()`

Wamp icon > PHP > PHP Extensions > `openssl` + `curl` are enabled.

Help appreciated.

Comment: reconfirm in your `phpinfo` page, does those are enabled? Also try restart services.

Comment: Make sure you have all the requirements: https://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.requirements.php because PHP 7.0.10 only needs version 0.9.8 but PHP 7.1.0 and newer require version 1.0.1